# Azure - Efficiently run code at specific time, not on a schedule

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I need the ability for users to enter in specific times in advance and have those users alerted in realtime at those times. I can have users alerted to-the-minute, but I'd prefer to alert users as close to the second as possible.

The best I can come up with is to set up an Azure Function Timer Trigger that runs every minute and checks to see if that time has come up, but it seems wasteful since we currently have a low number of times this code needs to get called, and that would only work to-the-minute.

Is there a better way to go about this with Azure?

Comment: Consider using Azure Storage Queues / Service Bus

Comment: I can see how that’s a good idea to make the code more robust, but how does it help with the scheduling issue?

Comment: There is "Visibility timeout" in Azure Storage Queues. When sending a message you can set the `TimeSpan` after which it will become visible on the queue. Sorry, not sure about Service Bus (may be mixed up something).

Comment: Other option is as you mentioned: store a message from the queue to a Table Storage by function #1, and then run function #2 on timer each 1 minute to process all current items. But it's not real-time. For real-time I don't see possibilities with Azure Functions. You can just run API with hosted service which keeps state in memory and each second triggers relevant alerts. Either, use https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/features.html for that

Comment: I unfortunately can't use visibility timeout as I can't guarantee users will enter in a value within 7 days, the maximum allowed. I'll consider either a Timer Trigger or a separate server running Quartz.

Comment: With the Service Bus you can schedule a message to be delivered at a certain time. The message receiver won't receive a message until the Scheduled Date has passed. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sequencing#scheduled-messages

Comment: Service Bus with scheduled messages is probably what I need, but I’m still looking into it.

Comment: @Anonymous1 Is executing TimeTrigger at a specific time what you want?

Comment: @BowmanZhu I’d need to programmatically create and delete a number of timer triggers, which is not optimal. I’m probably going with Azure Service Bus.

Comment: @DavidC Thanks for that link. Service Bus is exactly what I needed.